# Using finally for different exceptions with merry

Tags: python, python-3.x, merry

I came across merry, and I found it really interesting. However, according to the docs, the `@merry._finally` decorator only appears to be available without arguments. However, I would like to be able to have different `finally` clauses depending on the exception raised.

For instance:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any
from merry import Merry

merry = Merry()

class ExceptionNoneLinkedList(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message = "Linked List was Empty (head node was None)"):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(message)

class ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message = "Linked List can not be init with a None"):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(message)
        
@merry._except(ExceptionNoneLinkedList)
def ExceptionNoneLinkedListError(e):
    pass

@merry._except(ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList)
def ExceptionNoneLinkedListError(e):
    pass

@dataclass
class Node:
    attr: Any
    nxt : Node
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.attr)
       
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head: Node):
        self.head = head 
    
    def reverse(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise ExceptionNoneLinkedList()
            
        actual = self.head
        prev = None
        while actual is not None:
            nxt = actual.nxt
            actual.nxt = prev
            prev = actual
            actual = nxt
        self.head = prev
        
@merry._try
def main():
    l = LinkedList(None)
    l.reverse()
    
main()
```

Now suppose that `finally` is something like:

```
@merry._finally
def merry_finally():
    print("you rock!")
```

Is it possible to distinguish between the exceptions created here? Or I can only use `finally` for every exception? I would like to have two different `finally` functions.

Edit:
I didn't explain myself.
In regular Python, we have

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
finally:
    ...
```

However, `merry` gives us some decorators, so we can add them to the functions we want to execute when some exception is catched. This is done by adding `@merry._except(exception_name)`.

In the docs there is an example for `@merry._finally`, but it doesn't have any exception as argument. Now imagine, for instance, that I have two methods, one that works on a database and other that works on a file. I would like to use a `db.close` in a `finally` block for the first method, and a `print("hi")` for the other method.

In plain python, a `finally` block comes after a `try`, so it knows when to be executed, and you can have multiple `finally` in different `try`, so my question is if there is a way to have this kind of behaviour in `mery`.

Comment: You don't have the info in python normally either, so the hoops are the same.

Comment: What is merry and why is there no tag for it?

Comment: If you want to look at the type of exception, then you're handling the exception, which is done in an `except` block. Even if you plan to reraise the exception, you're still doing *handling* work. Using `finally` for this would be like using `while` to implement `if-else`; it can be done but it's not the point of the construct and will confuse people reading your code.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think I'm not explaining myself, so I'm going to edit the OP

Comment: I still don't understand. It sounds like this library is just wrapping your function in a `try ... finally` block. How can it possibly "not know" where it's going to run? It's going to run on the function you put it on; it definitely knows that. And, in your particular example, wouldn't the two `finally` blocks be the same anyway: just call `.close` on the resource? The point of Python's duck typing is that there *is* no difference between `.close` on a file and `.close` on a database; they look exactly the same.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm asking how to handle different behaviours for `finally` depending on the `try` that was executed before, because we agree in the fact that we can have more than one behaviour for `finally`, right? The example was just that, imagine that I want to print hi instead of closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

This reflects the [`try-except-finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) structure in normal python: a [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) block gets no arguments. The common python workaround is to get the current exception information from [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). However, this only works within an `except` block, so something like this:

```
from sys import exc_info

@merry._finally
def merry_finally():
    type, value, traceback = exc_info()
    if type is None:
        print('Clean exit')
    elif issubclass(type, ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList):
        print('Got a ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList')
    ...
```

will always print `Clean exit`.

A workaround is to register the exceptions of interest as you get them. For example, you could add an extra method to do that:

```
current_exception = [None, None, None] # List to avoid explicit global

def register_current_exception():
    current_exception[:] = sys.exc_info()

@merry._except(ExceptionNoneLinkedList)
def ExceptionNoneLinkedListError(e):
    ...
    register_current_exception()

@merry._except(ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList)
def ExceptionNoneLinkedListError(e):
    ...
    register_current_exception()

@merry._except(Exception)  # Don't catch errors, thats for the system
def Catchall(e):
    ...
    register_current_exception()
```

Then you can check if an exception was registered in the `finally` block:

```
@merry._finally
def merry_finally():
    type, value, traceback = current_exception
    if type is None:
        print('Clean exit')
    elif issubclass(type, ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList):
        print('Got a ExceptionNoneInitLinkedList')
    ...
```

Comment: I know I can make a workaround like this, but I would like to check if there is a way to do it with `merry`, just for it to be more pythonic. Finally gets no arguments, but you can know which `try` `except` executed it.

Comment: @Norhther. You can't know which except executed it, only the try.